# Cartthrob: confirmation email sent but member not registered

Tags: members, cartthrob, profile-edit

I'm having an issue on a site running EE v2.5.5 and Cartthrob 2.3.6. The vast majority of users are able to register no problem. However, some users intermittently go through the registration process, receive a confirmation email, but when they try to login they get the error: The existing username and/or password you submitted are not valid.

When you check in the backend of the site the member is not registered. I can't for the life of me find any pattern. I thought it might be something to do with people registering from work, where companies have some kind of excessive caching on their servers which is confusing EE somehow.

If anyone has experienced something similar please feel free to share the pain, and even better a solution!

Comment: Are you using CT in combination with Profile:Edit or any other member focused addon or is this straight CT and EE member registrations?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. I'm using Profile:Edit v.1.1.7

Comment: Does this just happen during CartThrob's "register at checkout" process, or is it every registration on the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we think we finally found the answer. The previous developer was setting some javascript when a user was registering that was posting the email address to another area of the db. This was causing some issues with certain versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

I can't offer a specific fix, but I would make sure you have the most recent version of EE, CartThrob and Profile:Edit installed to eliminate bugs in the code.